# How to define case insensitive macro names in m4?

Tags: bash, shell, macros, preprocessor, m4

Is there a way to make a macro name case insensitive when defining it?

For example,
Consider the input stream: `Mov MOV moV mOv`
I want the `m4` to output to be: `mov mov mov mov`

The naive way to do this is to define the following `m4` macros:

```sh
define(Mov,mov)
define(MOV,mov)
define(moV,mov)
define(mOv,mov)
```

This method becomes tedious when we want to do the same for a 4 or 5 letter word. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only string transform (*want the m4 to output to be*) you can use `translit`:

> ```
>      translit(string, mapfrom, mapto)
>               Transliterate the characters in the first argument from the
>               set given by the second argument to the set given by the
>               third.  You cannot use tr(1) style abbreviations.
> ```

Your case:

```
translit(`MoV',`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Let's create an m4 macro called to_lowercase. Its definition looks as shown below.

```
define(`to_lowercase',`translit($1,`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')')
```

Now, we can call our macro using `to_lowercase(Mov)',` to_lowercase(mOV)'.

Comment: Thanks for this function!

Comment: I was able to figure out a macro definition using this `translit()` function. I am unable to edit your answer so, I will post my solution here. Please add this to your answer. I will then accept your answer :)

Comment: Let's create an m4 macro called `to_lowercase`. Its definition looks as shown below. 
```define(`to_lowercase',`translit($1,`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')')
```
Now, we can call our macro using `to_lowercase(Mov)`, `to_lowercase(mOV)`, etc. It will give the output mov.

Comment: Now, that I think about it. This still doesn't solve the problem. I need to manually call the `to_lowercase` macro for each `Mov` present in the input stream. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Do you need *every* word to lowercase from an input (is it file or...?)? Or do you have only some specified words which should be lowercase?

Comment: I need only specific words present in the input file to be lowercase. 
For Example,
Let's I have an `input.asm` and its contents are:

`Mov AH,2 MOV al,bl moV aH,76`

Now, I want its output to be:
`mov AH,2 mov al,bl mov aH,76`
Here, only the word _mov_ is converted to lowercase.

Comment: Oh. And why do you want use `m4` instead of `sed` or similar?

Comment: I was just reading about `m4` so, I was thinking about how to solve this problem using `m4`. If sed is more suitable then it is okay.

Comment: I will accept your ans now, but please mention that sed is more suitable. Thanks!

Comment: I think the following is useful: `sed 's,mov,MOV,i ; s,another,ANOTHER,i'`